# Spring data mongodb sort on multiple fields

Tags: java, mongodb, mongodb-query, aggregation-framework, spring-data-mongodb

I want to sort on multiple fields in MongoDB using Spring data for MongoDB. Currently I am trying to achieve this using aggregation:

```
    Aggregation agg = newAggregation( 
            match(Criteria.where("userId").is(userId)), 
            sort(Sort.Direction.DESC, "type", "createdDate"), 
    );
    AggregationResults<MyBean> results = mongoOperations.aggregate(agg, MyBean.class, MyBean.class);
```

When I am doing this, it is sorting on the `type` and `createdDate` on `DESC` order. But I want `DESC` on `type` and `ASC` on `createdDate`.

I tried,

```
    sort(Sort.Direction.DESC, "type");
    sort(Sort.Direction.ASC, "createdDate");
```

but this is sorting only on `createdDate`.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can try something like this.

```
Aggregation agg = newAggregation(
        match(Criteria.where("userId").is(userId)),
        sort(Sort.Direction.DESC, "type").and(Sort.Direction.ASC, "createdDate")
);
```

Answer (score 4):

Little bit late, but for other people...
Try this (for spring-data):

```
private static final Sort NOTE_SORT = new Sort(new Sort.Order(Sort.Direction.ASC, "seen"),
                                                new Sort.Order(Sort.Direction.DESC, "date"),
                                                new Sort.Order(Sort.Direction.ASC, "done"));
```

Answer (score 3):

You can create order list and use it for sort like this

```
List<Order> orders = new ArrayList<>();
orderQuery.add(new Order(Direction.DESC, "createdDate"));
Sort sorts = new Sort(orders.toArray(new Order[orders.size()]));    
Aggregation agg = newAggregation(
        match(Criteria.where("userId").is(userId)),
        sort(sorts)
);
```

Answer (score 0):

Simple sorting without Aggregation object

```
import org.springframework.data.domain.Sort;
import org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.MongoTemplate;

//query: existing mongo query
//mongoTemplate: @Autowired MongoTemplate object
//First create a list of Sort.Order and add multiple criteria's

List<Sort.Order> sortOnMultipleFIelds = new ArrayList<>();
            sortOnMultipleFIelds.add(new Sort.Order(Sort.Direction.DESC, "Field1"));
            sortOnMultipleFIelds.add(new Sort.Order(Sort.Direction.ASC, "Field2"));
            sortOnMultipleFIelds.add(new Sort.Order(Sort.Direction.DESC, "Field3"));


//Apply it on Query
            query.with(Sort.by(sortOnMultipleFIelds);

//Execute query
            List<ClassName> resultList= mongoTemplate.find(query, ClassName.class);
```